# Remove google markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have a script which creats makers on the map from some custom fields. Before i've inserted ajax in my page , the markers reseted when i was changing the page.Now, after i've inserted the ajax , i need to reset my markers and recreate them after i trigger an event. How do i reset my markers? Here it's my code for google map. Thanks !

```
(function($) {
    'use strict';
    var marker = [];
    function handleHouse(house, map, geocoder, infowindow) {
        geocoder.geocode({'address': house.address}, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: results[0].geometry.location
                });

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                    infowindow.setContent(house.title + house.desc);
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                });
            }
        });
    }

    function handleHouses(houses, map, geocoder, infowindow) {
        for (var id in houses) {
            if (houses.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
                handleHouse(houses[id], map, geocoder, infowindow);
            }
        }
    }

    $(function() {
        if (typeof HOUSE_DATA === 'undefined') {
            return;
        }

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 11,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(36.5819074, -4.8703777,11.25),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

        handleHouses(HOUSE_DATA, map, geocoder, infowindow);

        $('#houses-result').on('houses-refresh', function() {
            alert ('markers reseted');
            handleHouses(HOUSE_DATA, map, geocoder, infowindow);
        });
    });
}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should store refferences to your markers in an array, this way you can iterate over the array and manipulate with markers. [Here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-remove) is an example showing how to hide all markers on the map. Alternating this example you should be able to change markers in any manner you want.

So it should look like this:

```
var marker = [];
var markers = [];
function handleHouse(house, map, geocoder, infowindow) {
    geocoder.geocode({'address': house.address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location
            });
            markers.push(marker);
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                infowindow.setContent(house.title + house.desc);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

And then the recreation:

```
$('#houses-result').on('houses-refresh', function() {
    alert ('markers reseted');
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
         markers[i].setMap(null);
    }
    markers = [];
    handleHouses(HOUSE_DATA, map, geocoder, infowindow);
});
```